# question about Graph Theory notation

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation, definition

I'm just starting to learn graph theory. I have two questions about notation:

1). For a graph $G$ we denote the vertex set $V$ and the edge set $E$ by $G=(V,E)$.
So we have a graph $G=$ ({$v_{1},v_{2},...,v_n$}, {$e_{1}e_{2},...e_{n}$}).
My textbook presents the edge set as $E=${($v_1,v_2$), ($v_1,v_3$),...,($v_i,v_n$)}.
If I remember correctly, set theory rules tell us that ( ) are used to indicate order, and { } are used when the order doesn't matter. Why are ( ) used in this case when denoting the vertices in the edge set?

2). I'm used to seeing this formula, $E\subseteq V\times V$, to indicate a relation on $V$ denoting the elements of $E\subseteq V\times V$ as edges. In another set of notes that I stumbled upon, this notation is used: $E\subseteq V\bigotimes V$ as edges. What is the $\bigotimes$, I'm confused about that.

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is a directed graph, where an edge has a direction? Another notation I have seen is $[V]^2$ which the set of all two element subsets of $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of vertices in an edge *is* important if we consider directed edges.
The notation as pairs of vertices (which does not allow multiple edges, by the way!) fits well with viewing $E$ as subset of $V\times V$. The notation $\otimes$ is rather known from linear algebra where it denoites the tensor product, while here it apparently stands for the set of *unordered* pairs ov elements of $V$ (as needed for undirected graphs). Cf. also the notations $V^2$ for $V\times V$ versus $[V]^2$ for $V\otimes V$.